# What Font is being used in this SKITCHS logo?

Tags: fonts

[image]

Can someone please help me identify this font or typeface?

Comment: It's not a font, it's a drawing. There are 2 too different S-letters. It maybe started from a text which was written by using a blocky font.  Impossible to be sure what is done manually and which features utilize effects. It can be as well put together only by moving rotated and skewed letters and by painting the rest. Or some 3D effect may be used to get the apparent thickness and only the black erosions are painted manually. It's your job to search the possible starting font. You can try Eurostile family fonts. Every letter can as well be a 100% manual drawing - no font nor effects.